# Does jOOQ support linked SQL Servers?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, amazon-rds, jooq

This seems like a fairly straight-forward question, but I can't track down an answer without testing it:

Does jOOQ support linked SQL Servers? (SQL Server 2008 R2). We have an application running in a SQL Server R2 AWS-RDS instance and it's running out of space, so we're looking at various options. The one we're favoring right now is moving a specific set of data onto it's own RDS instance (for good architectural reasons).

We're trying to determine what the impact of doing this would be to our application tier.

Does anyone know if the jOOQ code generator creates objects for linked servers?

Comment: The interesting question is: Are linked instances and their related artefacts exposed through the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`? (see also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16081129/521799))

Answer (score 1):

Officially, this has never been tested explicitly. It might work, depending on how SQL Server exposes linked instances. jOOQ's code generator runs queries against SQL Server's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. I.e. it can generate all artefacts that it will find in those views.

Note, even if jOOQ cannot generate artefacts from a linked instance, you could connect to that instance directly with the jOOQ code generator, and try to use the [codegen-time or runtime schema mapping features](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/code-generation/schema-mapping/), in order to generate the link prefixes.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. The project got de-prioritized right after I posted this note, so I haven't had a chance to verify your answer, but this looks reasonable. We'll try the various approaches in a test and let you know how it goes.